# $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Wanting to check my proof that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^3$.

Strategy:

Use the isomorphism $\tilde{H}^*(\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^3;\mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq \tilde{H}^*(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}_2) \times \tilde{H}^*(S^3;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ of reduced cohomology rings and the fact that homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic cohomology rings to obtain a contradiction.

I computed that $\tilde{H}^*(S^n;\mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq \langle \beta | \beta^2 = 2\beta = 0 \rangle$ where $|\beta|=n$ is the degree of $\beta$.

Also we know that $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n;\mathbb{Z}_2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1})$, where $|\alpha|=1$, so that the reduced cohomology rings are the same except without nonzero constants on the polynomials.

My conclusion is that in $\tilde{H}^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}_2) \times \tilde{H}^*(S^3;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ the cube of every element is zero since over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, we have

$(a\alpha + b \alpha^2)^3=a^2\alpha^2(a\alpha+b\alpha^2)=0 \implies (a\alpha + b \alpha^2,\beta) \in \tilde{H}^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}_2) \times \tilde{H}^*(S^3;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ has zero cube.

On the other hand, in $\mathbb{R}P^3$ we have $\alpha^3 \neq 0$.

> Did I make any mistakes here? I am also dubious about the cohomology ring for the sphere since it seems rather weird.

Comment: Another way to write the (unreduced) cohomology ring for the sphere is $\mathbb{Z}_2[\beta]/(\beta^2)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese That looks right. I was working with the reduced cohomology ring because the isomorphism for the wedge sum doesn't hold for unreduced.

Comment: That's true, but it only fails in degree zero.

Comment: What do you mean by $\langle\beta \mid \beta^2 = 2\beta = 0\rangle$ in the context of rings?

Comment: Normally you would write the cohomology ring of $S^n$ as the exterior algebra $H^*(S^n)=\Lambda_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(x_n)$ on a class $x_n$ of degree $n$. This means that it is the free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module in degree $n$, generated by the class $x_n$ which satisfies $x_n^2=0$. This is just the technical name for exactly what you have have. (See Hatcher ex 3.13, pg 213)